# Unable to select drop down list

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am running on:
windows 7
watir-webdriver 0.6.4
selenium-webdriver (2.35.1, 2.35.0, 2.31.0)

```
<div>
    //more embedded codes...
    <div id="emd1" class="ui-select" style="float: left; width: 90%;">
        <a id="emb1" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-d" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="emb1" data-theme="d">
            <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all" aria-hidden="true">
                <span class="ui-btn-text">Choose one... </span>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow"></span>
            </span>
        </a>
        <select id="emu1" data-placeholder="true" data-native-menu="false" serial="1" sequenceid="1" tabindex="-1">
            <option value="">Choose one...</option>
            <option value="A">Apple </option>
            <option value="B">Banana </option>
            <option value="C">Cat </option>
            <option value="D">Dog </option>
            <option value="E">Elephant </option>
            <option value="F">Fish </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

whenever I want to select ddl, I just do this all the time and it always worked fine

```
browser.select_list(:id = "emu1").select("Apple")
```

and it will get the job done.  Suddenly it stop working.  I am not sure if its due to recent upgrade I did on selenium-webdriver, and watir-webdriver.  Or due to code change.

```
browser.a(:id => "emb1").wait_until_present
```

works fine

```
browser.select_list(:id => "emu1").wait_until_present
```

wait for 30 sec and giving me the couldn't find element error.

anyone else having any similar issue?  Any help is good. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth, your example worked for me on Win7 + wwd 0.6.4 + selenium-webdriver 2.33.0.  Also, I noticed a typo in your example: `=` instead of `=> ` in `browser.select_list(:id = "emu1").select("Apple")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing the CSS that displays the HTML I cannot be 100% certain, but I have a hunch the user-facing select list is actually a styled `<span>`. The `<select>` is likely being hidden by CSS. If the `<select>` is hidden by CSS, webdriver is unable to 'see' the it.

To expose select lists like this, I've used JavaScript to alter the `select`'s `display` attribute.  I've added this snippet to my watir-webdriver toolbox before accessing fancy `select_lists`:

```rb
script = %q{document.getElementById("emu1").style.display = "block");}
browser.execute_script(script)
```

This alters the display properties of the select list, so it can now accessed by the all of the `select_list` commands available to webdriver.

You can give this a try by heading to the page with the select list and opening the developer console of your preferred web browser. Try the following and see if you now see a select list appear:

```
document.getElementById("emu1").style.display = "block";
```

If that doesn't work, try using `display = "inline"`. If a standard HTML select list now displays, you've found the culprit and the solution.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  It worked before and now its now working, the only thing I did in between is update the selenium-webdriver.  I went back to old version which is (2.31.0) and everything works fine.